# Parser BBCode ignorar o que estiver dentro de [code]

Tags: php, regex

Fiz um bbcode parser baseado em alguns para atender minhas necessidades, porém tenho alguns problemas.

1. O código dentro de [code] deve ser ignorado, mas não sei como eu poderia fazer isso, já que tem todas as outras tags que são parseadas.

Tentei fazer assim, não atendeu 100%

```
$pos = strpos($text, '[code]');
    $code = "";

    if($pos!==false){

        $code = substr($text, $pos, strpos($text, '[/code]')-$pos);
        $text = str_replace($code.'[/code]','',$text);
        $code = substr($code, 6);
    }
```

Comment: Daniel edite sua pergunta e deixe somente o código relevante ao que está sendo perguntado.

Comment: Você quer apagar todos os blocos de texto dentro do seguinte formato: `[code]***código***[/code]`

Comment: @Daniel Lemes meu exemplo não serviu? se não, pode detalhar melhor?

Comment: @CIRCLE sim quero pegar o que está dentro de code e guarda em outra variável retirando isso da string principal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Talvez essa resposta seja MUITO a mais daquilo que você precisa, mas na minha opinião não basta você ter apenas uma Expressão Regular ou uma solução baseada nas posições de determinados caracteres (ainda mais porque isso requer que o dado de entrada esteja perfeitamente normalizado).

Sendo assim, proponho uma solução orientada a Objetos onde um *Parser* aplica tantas estratégias de substituição quantas você tenha:

Primeiro a estrutura dos arquivos:

```
|-\BBCode
| |-\BBCode\Parser.php
| \-\BBCode\Parsers
|   |-\BBCode\Parsers\Code.php
|   |-\BBCode\Parsers\Emphasis.php
|   |-\BBCode\Parsers\Parser.php
|   \-\BBCode\Parsers\Strong.php
\-\index.php
```

**BBCode\Parser.php** é nossa classe de acesso às diferentes estratégias de análise e substiuição:

```
<?php

namespace BBCode;

class Parser {

    /**
     * Available Parsers
     *
     * @var array parsers
     */
    private $parsers = array();

    /**
     * Input Text (with BBCodes)
     *
     * @var string $text;
     */
    protected $text;

    /**
     * Output Text (parsed)
     *
     * @var string $output;
     */
    protected $output;

    /**
     * Parser Constructor
     * Prepares the text to be parsed
     */
    public function __construct( $text ) {

        // Preparing text

        $text = $this -> prepare( $text );

        $this -> text = $this -> output = $text;
    }

    /**
     * Add new BBCode Parser to be used
     *
     * @param Parsers\Parser $parser
     *  BBCode Parser
     *
     * @return BBCode\Parser
     *  Parser Object (Fluent Interface)
     */
    public function addParser( Parsers\Parser $parser ) {

        $this -> parsers[] = $parser;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Parses BBCodes
     *
     * @return BBCode\Parser
     *  Parser Object (Fluent Interface)
     */
    public function parse() {

        foreach( $this -> parsers as $parser ) {

            $this -> output = $parser -> parse( $this -> output );
        }

        return $this;
    }

    // Accessors

    /**
     * Get output (parsed) text
     *
     * @return string
     *  Parsed text
     */
    public function getText() {
        return $this -> output;
    }

    // Auxiliary Methods

    /**
     * Applies some routines over inout text
     * allowing easier parsing
     *
     * @param string $text
     *  Text to cleanup
     *
     * @return string
     *  Cleaned text
     */
    private function prepare( $text ) {

        // Cleaning trailing spaces

        $text = trim( $text );

        // Removing duplicated spaces

        $text = preg_replace( '/\s{2,}/', ' ', $text );

        return $text;
    }
}
```

Parece demais só por causa dos comentários, mas é realmente muito simples. Nela temos, além das propriedades, claro:

- O construtor para receber o dado de entrada o qual será trabalhado por cada *Parser* individual;
- Um método (*Parser::addParser()*) através do qual possamos adicionar novas estratégias de *Parsing*, tudo assegurado com interfaces e polimorfismo através do *type-hinting*.
- Um método que itera a coleção de *Parsers* e os aplica em lote ao texto de entrada
- Um *getter* para obtermos o texto com os BBCodes substituídos pelas tags apropriadas.

Temos também um método privado que permite simplificar as possíveis Expressões Regulares das estratégias de análise. Eu adicionei apenas duas rotinas: Uma para limpar espaços ao redor da string e outra para remover espaços duplicados.

Essas duas rotinas nos permite, por exemplo, não precisar de bordas ( \b ), âncoras ( ^ e $ ) ou o barra-letra de caracteres não imprimíveis ( \s ).

Temos então as classes responsáveis pelas estratégias de *parsing*:

**Strong.php**

```
namespace BBCode\Parsers;

class Strong implements Parser {

    /**
     * Parses found BBCodes
     *
     * @param string $text
     *  Input text to parse
     */
    public function parse( $text ) {

        $text = $this -> applyParsingRestrictions( $text );

        return preg_replace_callback(

            '/\[b\](.*?)\[\/b\]/',

            function( $matches ) {
                return sprintf( '<strong>%s</strong>', $matches[ 1 ] );
            },

            $text
        );
    }

    // Auxiliary methods

    /**
     * Apply parsing restrictions against nested BBCodes
     *
     * @param string $text
     *  Input Text to analyze
     *
     * @return string
     *  Input text with nested BBCodes striped
     */
    private function applyParsingRestrictions( $text ) {

        if( preg_match( '/((?<=\[code\])\[b\])(.*)(\[\/b\](?=\[\/code\]))/', $text, $matches ) ) {

            $text = str_replace(

                sprintf( '[b]%s[/b]', $matches[ 2 ] ), $matches[ 2 ], $text
            );
        }

        return $text;
    }
}
```

**Emphasis.php**

```
namespace BBCode\Parsers;

class Emphasis implements Parser {

    /**
     * Parses found BBCodes
     *
     * @param string $text
     *  Input text to parse
     */
    public function parse( $text ) {

        return preg_replace_callback(

            '/\[i\](.*?)\[\/i\]/',

            function( $matches ) {
                return sprintf( '<em>%s</em>', $matches[ 1 ] );
            },

            $text
        );
    }
}
```

**Code.php**

```
<?php

namespace BBCode\Parsers;

class Code implements Parser {

    /**
     * Parses found BBCodes
     *
     * @param string $text
     *  Input text to parse
     */
    public function parse( $text ) {

        return preg_replace_callback(

            '/\[code\](.*?)\[\/code\]/',

            function( $matches ) {
                return sprintf( '<code>%s</code>', $matches[ 1 ] );
            },

            $text
        );
    }
}
```

E você pode criar tantas estratégias quantas você precisar, bastando que todas elas implementem o método definido na interface *Parsers\Parser.php*:

```
<?php

namespace BBCode\Parsers;

interface Parser {

    /**
     * Parses found BBCodes
     *
     * @param string $text
     *  Input text to parse
     */
    public function parse( $text );
}
```

As rotinas de substituição são quase auto-explicativas. É uma substituição regular simples. Eu optei por [preg_replace_callback()](http://www.php.net/preg_replace_callback) por ser mais legível.

O pulo-do-gato que (finalmente) contextualiza essa resposta à questão do tópico foi demonstrada apenas na classe **Strong.php** através do método *Strong::applyParsingRestrictions()*.

Antes de a substituição dos BBCodes **[b]** e **[/b]** serem feitas por suas contra-partes **<strong>** e **</strong>** é feita uma busca por outros BBCodes que possam estar englobando àqueles referente ao negrito.

Eu defini apenas uma busca, pelo BBCode **[code]**. Se o BBCode de negrito for encontrado dentro de um BBcode de código, ao invés de darmos prosseguimento à substituição pelas tags HTML, nós removemos o BBCode do texto de entrada.

E a idéia é basicamente [aquela postada pelo Guilherme Lautert](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/28914/250), utilizanado *lookbacks* e *lookaheads*. Olhamos para trás procurando pela abertura do BBCode de código e olhamos para frente pelo BBCode de fechamento, se encontrar, removemos os BBCodes de negrito que existir dentro.

E de volta ao método de interface *Parsers\Parser::parse()*, caso não exista nenhuma outra ocorrência do BBCode de negrito, [preg_replace_callback()](http://www.php.net/preg_replace_callback) não será executado, retornando o fluxo para o próximo *Parser* da coleção definida.

Para usar isso tudo temos:

```
<?php

// Autoloading

spl_autoload_register( function( $classname ) {

    $classname = stream_resolve_include_path(

        str_replace( '\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $classname ) . '.php'
    );

    if( $classname !== FALSE ) {

        include $classname;
    }
});

$parser = new BBCode\Parser(

    '[code][b]This[/b][/code]       [code][i]is[/i][/code] my [b]text[/b]  !'
);

$parser -> addParser( new BBCode\Parsers\Strong )
        -> addParser( new BBCode\Parsers\Emphasis )
        -> addParser( new BBCode\Parsers\Code );

echo $parser -> parse() -> getText();

?>
```

E temos como saída;

```
<code>This</code> <code><em>is</em></code> my <strong>text</strong> !
```

Veja a aplicação de restrição em ação. Nossa string de entrada tem um BBCode de negrito dentro de outro de código. Por causa da restrição, removemos o de negrito deixando apena os de código.

Isso sem prejuízo do BBCode de negrito definido mais a frente, que funciona normalmente.

Mas veja o que aconteceu com o BBCode de itálico (*emphasis*). Como não foi definida nenhuma regra de restrição, a string resultante teve um **<em>** dentro de um **<code>**.

Eu escrevi esse código agora, bem rápido. Não levei em conta abstração para não complicar mais do que já compliquei. Num caso real é bastante interessante abstrair para que um mesmo sistema aceite tanto BBCodes quanto, quem sabe, **Markdown**.

Answer (score 4):

**Possível solução:**

```
<?php

   $code = '
   teste[code]123[/code]bla 
   teste[code]456[/code]bla 
   teste[code]789[/code]bla 
   teste[code]xyz[/code]bla
';

   While ( $pos = stripos( ' '.$code, '[code]') ) {
      $left = substr( $code, 0, $pos - 1 );
      $code = substr( $code, $pos + 5 );
      $right = substr( $code, stripos( $code, '[/code]' ) + 7 );

      // Se quiser fazer algo com o código que foi removido faça nesta linha:
      echo htmlentities( 'Removido: '.substr( $code, 0, stripos( $code, '[/code]' ) ) ).'<br>';

      $code = $left.$right;
   }

   echo 'Resultado: '.nl2br( htmlentities( $code ) );

?>
```

Esse loop basicamente remove tudo entre `[code]` e `[/code]` da string original, incluindo as tags. Algumas considerações:

- Se quiser extrair apenas `[code]` em minúsculas, troque o `stripos` por `strpos`;
- se quiser fazer algo com o código removido, basta usar a lógica abaixo do *comment*;
- dependendo como for processar os dados, talvez fosse melhor ignorar os dados na hora de os apresentar, e não removendo realmente da *string* original;
- o código acima ignora tags não fechadas; é o caso de você decidir se tag não fechada conta até o fim da linha, ou deixa como está.

**Resultado:**

```
Removido: 123
Removido: 456
Removido: 789
Removido: 444
Resultado: 
 testebla 
 testebla 
 testebla 
 testebla
```

Answer (score 1):

Daniel, não sei se intendi direito o que você necessita, mas tente:

```
    $str = "texte 1 [code] texte code [/code] texte 2";     

    preg_match('/(?<=\[code\]).*(?=\[\/code\])/', $str, $match);

    $strCode = $match[0];
```

isso ira retorna tudo que tiver dentro de "[code][/code]"

Comment: Putz cara, agora com o que o $Bacco fez eu intendi o que o cara queria, mas tambem foi falta de interesse do @Daniel Lemes, porque minha resposta da quase no mesmo, so tem que trocar para "preg_match_all" e "$strCode = $match".

Answer (score 1):

Acho que é mais ou menos isso, basta modificar a função dentro do `preg_replace_callback` para o que você precisa:

```
$text = "Teste de string com code: [code]<p>teste</p>[/code] e continuação de teste com outro code: [code]<p>teste 2</p>[/code] com mais texto.";

$text = preg_replace_callback('/\[code\](.*?)\[\/code\]/i',
        function ($matches) {
            return ($matches[1] ? '<div class="code">' . htmlspecialchars($matches[1], ENT_COMPAT,'ISO-8859-1') . '</div>' : '');
        }, $text);

echo $text;

// retorno

// Teste de string com code: <div class="code">&lt;p&gt;teste&lt;/p&gt;</div> e continuação de teste com outro code: <div class="code">&lt;p&gt;teste 2&lt;/p&gt;</div> com mais texto.
```

Neste exemplo, a função adiciona o conteúdo das tags `[code]` dentro de um `div`, e converte os caracteres HTML para que eles sejam exibidos.
A classe `.code`, pode ser usada para formatar a `div` com background, borda, fonte, etc...

E se encontrar `[code][/code]`, elas são removidas sem criar um `div` vazio.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer com expressão regular assim:

```
<?php 
function removeBB($texto) { 
    $regex = '|[[\/\!]*?[^\[\]]*?]|si';  
    return preg_replace($regex, '', $texto); 
} 
$s = "[url=http://google.com.br]Google[/url]"; 
echo removeBB($s); 
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Este regex pode resolver o problema.

```
<?php

$string = 'texto texto la la la [code]<html><iframe><p>codigo html.</p></iframe></html>[/code] continuacao do texto e bla bla bla';
$pattern = '%(\[code\].*\[/code\])%';
$replacement = "${1}[code][/code]";
$response = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);

print $response;

?>
```

**output**
texto texto la la la [code][/code] continuacao do texto e bla bla bla